# Integer to Binary Conversion Program Fails for Some Inputs

Tags: c, binary, integer

I wrote code for getting binary form of an integer. It works well for inputs like 1 or 10. However, it is failing for inputs like 256. (It gives 0000000 s output and misses the one).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int number_of_binary_digits_required(int n){

return ceil(log(n))+1;

}

void print_array(int * a, int n){

    int i = 0;
    for (;i<n;i++){
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    }

}


int main(){

int num = 256;
int binary[100];
int n = number_of_binary_digits_required(num);
int bin_digits = n-1;

while (num){

   int temp = num%2;
   num = num / 2;
   binary[bin_digits] = temp;
   //printf("%d\n", bin_digits);
   bin_digits--;

}

print_array(binary, n);

//printf("%d", number_of_binary_digits_required(num));
//for(bin_digits = 0;bin_digits < number_of_binary_digits_required(num);bin_digits++)
//printf("%d",binary[bin_digits]);


}
```

Why is the issue coming and how to resolve it?

Thanks you!

Comment: You don't even need to calculate the number of digits in advance. You can write digits from `num % 2` into a buffer until `(num /= 2) == 0`, and then print them in reverse order, or, store them in a buffer in reverse order.

Comment: @WeatherVane thanks, i was trying to do in the forward way..did it using the reverse way correctly..

Comment: I was editing as you typed: you can store them in reverse order without needing to know how many. Start at the end of a large enough buffer, then print the buffer from where you stopped. If that was at `binary[90]` then you can `printf("%s", binary + 90);` But you need a `NUL` terminator, and also to add `'0'` to each digit as it goes into the buffer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C's log function gives result with a base of e, not 2. This is why some numbers give unexpected result in your program since you calculate using that. There is a function [log2](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/log2/) which is what you need i think.

Comment: Ha. Good spot. Even so, there is the potential for undershoot. Less likely with binary floating point, but still be very careful. I’ll upvote this answer though.

Comment: `round` might be better than `ceil`.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Indeed it would.

Answer (score 1):

Your use of a logarithmic function to compute the number of digits in conjunction with ceil will suffer due to floating point undershoot.

A more reliable way of calculating the number of binary digits is to divide by two repeatedly until zero is attained.

Comment: why is floating point calculation wrong? Is log function not implemented correctly in mat.h..any replacements? could you give an example of undershooting...here i am not getting it..

Comment: You’ve seen an example in your code! Get the debugger out. The natural logarithm function is more than good enough for very many scientific applications, but it could be out on the 15th significant figure or perhaps worse than that, but your use of ceil essentially converts a smooth function to a discontinuous one, and that’s where all hell breaks loose.

Comment: thanks, but the log2 was a mistake..floor(log2) works great

Comment: @RONALDO69 `round` might be better than `floor` or `ceil`.

Comment: Be very very careful when using logs to count digits. I like the answer you accepted but it could bite you. That said, round would nail this.

Answer (score 0):

The first mistake is to use log(n), which calculates log of n base e.

Instead use log2(n)

Hope it helps. :-)